# Create pandas column based on names of two others

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a long pandas dataframe with many columns, I want to take two of them and build a new one as follow

```
    A   B    
0   1   1
1   0   1
2   1   0
3   0   0

    Aa  Bb  A_B  
0   1   1  'Both'
1   0   1  'B'
2   1   0  'A'
3   0   0  'None'
```

The values of the new column are: 'Both' if both the values of Aa and Bb are 1; 'B' is the value of column Bb is 1 and Aa is 0, and so on. I tried converting to string columns Aa and Bb, then concatenating them and replace the corresponding values, which works, but: is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiplication:

```
d = pd.Series(['None', 'A', 'B', 'Both'])
df['A_B'] = df[['A', 'B']].mul([1, 2]).sum(axis=1).replace(d)
print(df)

# Output
   A  B   A_B
0  1  1  Both
1  0  1     B
2  1  0     A
3  0  0  None
```

Details:

```
>>> d
0    None
1       A
2       B
3    Both
dtype: object
```

Multiply A by 1, B by 2 and sum on index axis. If the result is:

- `0`: None of A or B
- `1`: A only
- `2`: B only
- `3`: both A and B

Comment: Good idea with multiplication!

Answer (score 2):

`np.select` would be a fairly good choice

```
m = df[['A', 'B']].astype(bool)
df['A_B'] = np.select([m['A'] & m['B'], m['A'], m['B']], ['Both', 'A', 'B'], 'None')
```

---

```
   A  B   A_B
0  1  1  Both
1  0  1     B
2  1  0     A
3  0  0  None
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a mapping dictionary with tuples as keys:

```
m = {(1,1):'Both',(1,0):'A',(0,1):'B',(0,0):'None'}
df['A_B'] = df.apply(tuple,axis=1).map(m)
```

or you could create a new df and merge

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(1,1,'Both'),(1,0,'A'),(0,1,'B'),(0,0,'None')],columns = ['A','B','A_B'])
df = pd.merge(df,df2,how = 'left')
```

or

```
df['A_B'] = df.dot(df.columns).replace({'AB':'Both','':'None'})
```

Output:

```
   A  B   A_B
0  1  1  Both
1  0  1     B
2  1  0     A
3  0  0  None
```

Comment: I liked the merge approach

Answer (score 0):

By filtering Series index values on number `1`:

```
df['A_B'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.index[x.eq(1)].str.cat(), axis=1)\
            .replace({'AB': 'Both', '': 'None'})
```

---

```
   A  B   A_B
0  1  1  Both
1  0  1     B
2  1  0     A
3  0  0  None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`from_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.from_dummies.html) like:

This should work even if you have more than just two columns like A, B.

```
m1 = ~df.all(axis=1)
m2 = df.any(axis=1)
col_name = 'A_B'
df.loc[m1&m2, col_name] = pd.from_dummies(df[m1&m2]).apply('_'.join, axis=1).values
df.loc[~m1, col_name] = 'Both'
df.loc[~m2, col_name] = 'None'
print(df)

   Aa  Bb   A_B
0   1   1  Both
1   0   1    Bb
2   1   0    Aa
3   0   0  None
```